# How to resync the data in a view?

Tags: mysql, view

I have created a view and now I've added data to my original database, I want the added data to be synced or update my view.

My created view query:

```
CREATE VIEW test1.view AS SELECT * FROM test2.name;
```

Can you please help me with how to update my view?

Comment: Shamkat, please do not edit your existing questions with a completely different question. I've rolled that edit back. Feel free to post a **NEW** question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to "update" a view. It is **automatically** kept in sync with your actual data.

As soon as you update the `test2` table, your `test1` view will be immediately re-synced.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to update a `VIEW` because it is ***virtual table*** and only a ***projection of a `SELECT` statement***.

If you want to update it, you need to update the base table `test2.name`. Any modification on the base table will be reflected on the `VIEW`.

Comment: sory i added anothor question here